# jQuery .animate() doesn't work on the first time

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, slide

I'm making a "garage door" type thing to display projects. There is a div (`whole`) with a background image, then another div (`project_info`) that slides down with information, covering the background image of `whole`. It works exactly as I like, except that no matter what, the animation will not work the first time. All 3 elements (`project_info`, `project_name` and `project_desc`) slide down at the same speed when they should slide at different speeds. Every time after, though, the slide works.

HTML:

```
<div class="whole" style="background-image: url('rail.jpg');">
  <div class="project_info">
    <span class="project_name">Rail Direct</span>
    <span class="project_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".whole").hover(function() {
  $('.project_info').stop().animate({"top": "0px"}, 300);
  $('.project_name').stop().animate({"top": "0px"}, 1000);
  $('.project_desc').stop().animate({"top": "0px"}, 650);
},
function() {
  $('.project_info').stop().animate({"top": "-155px"}, 800);
  $('.project_name').stop().animate({"top": "-155px"}, 300);
  $('.project_desc').stop().animate({"top": "-155px"}, 650);
});
```

});

Probably important to note, the mouseout part of the hover will work the first time.

Comment: What is the starting "top" value of the elements you are animating?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/qG5Hh/1/

If you used position:relative then the internal spans would move at the same speed as the containing div plus their own speeds. I tried to get the result you were looking for by setting the height of the div instead of the top value.